# auto populating drop down result is not storing into mysql database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

i am using a form and i used javascript to populate the second dropdown menu when i select my first selection. everything is working fine in form second drowndown is being change and showing result depending on my selection. but after submitting the value of second dropdown menu is not beirng inserted in to mysql. its blank.

here is my form code.

```
<style type="text/css">
table,tr,td{border:0px solid black;}
</style>
  <table id="titlebar" cellspacing="0px">
        <tr>
            <td style="width:20px;">&#10003;</td>
            <td style="width:160px;">Show</td>
            <td style="width:62px;">season</td>
            <td style="width:63px;">episode</td>
            <td style="width:100px;">language</td>
            <td style="width:190px;">Link 1</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <form action="send.php" method="POST">
  <table id="dataTable" width="auto" style="margin:-4px 0 0 0;" cellspacing="0px">
    <tr>
      <td style="width:20px;"><INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk" /></td>
      <td><select name="series[]" onchange="showUser(this.value)"> <?php echo $item; ?></select></td>
            <td><select name="season[]" id="txtHint"> </ </select></td>
               </tr>
  </table>
    <INPUT type="button" value="Add row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />
  <INPUT type="button" value="Delete row" onclick="deleteRow('dataTable')" />
    <INPUT type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
    </form>
```

here is my javascrip to change dropdown menu

```
<script  src="jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
function showUser(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  } 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

here is my post code 
send.php

```
<?php

    include('mysql.php');

     if (isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
            $stockid = $_POST["series"];
            $desc = $_POST["season"];

            foreach($stockid as $a => $B)
            {

        mysql_query("INSERT INTO 0_stock_master (stock_id, description, long_description) VALUES ('$stockid[$a]','$desc[$a]')");
    } 
    }
    ?>
```

my problem is this that it is inserting `$stockid[$a]` but not inserting the `$desc[$a]`.....

Comment: does `$desc[$a]` have a value? Do a `print_r` on `$desc` and make sure it has values and has the same keys that `$stockid` does.

Comment: i used `echo stockid[$a];` its showing result but `echo desc[$a];` is not displaying anything its blank

Comment: Right do a `print_r($desc);` and let us know what the output is.

Comment: Also why are you even using arrays for `series` and `season` they are only on the html once?

Comment: no i an using a script to add multiple these rows. anyway that is working perfectly but not this

Comment: `print_r($desc);` is displaying this error `Array ( [0] => )`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45744/discussion-between-user3210029-and-pitchinnate)

Comment: FYI your going to have a problem with multiple rows if they all have and `id="txtHint"`

Comment: `<select name="season[]" id="txtHint"> </ </select>` there is an extra `</` in there but that should get overwritten when it gets populated by the javascript.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you have an error in the query

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO 0_stock_master 
  (stock_id, description, long_description) 
  VALUES 
 ('$stockid[$a]','$desc[$a]')");
```

You are trying to add 3 fields but in the value you have specified only 2 resulting mysql error.

Comment: sorry my mistake i forgot to erase that but No still not working

Comment: use mysql_error() which will tell you what went wrong with the query

Comment: its not displaying any error actually it is receiving `$_POST["season"]` blank. but why i dnt know